# Cannot deserialize a 'List<UserRole>' from BsonType 'String'

Tags: c#, mongodb, deserialization

[image: Mongodb User schema]I have collection json from MongoDb user collection as below

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "621f9073e27aaf55a5b9f9ac"
    },
    "FirstName": "test",
    "LastName": "test",
    "Email": "test@example.com",
    "CountryCode": "91",
    "Phone": "99887766",
    "Extension": "12",
    "UserRoles": [{
        "RoleId": 1,
        "RoleName": "RegisteringUser"
    }],
    "CreatedDate": {
        "$date": "2022-03-02T15:42:43.637Z"
    },
    "ModifiedDate": {
        "$date": "2022-03-02T15:42:43.637Z"
    }
}
```

Corresponding C# classes for this structure is as below

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class User : IEntity
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        [RepositoryID]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }

 public class UserRole
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
    }
```

Furthermore to get these details from Mongo Collection I have below repo call setup

```
public async Task<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(string id) where TEntity : IEntity
        {
            var dbCollection = _database.GetCollection<TEntity>(typeof(TEntity).GetCollectionName());
            var asyncCursor = await dbCollection.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id);
            return await asyncCursor.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

When I run this code through TestHarness integration Test,

```
await _repository.Get<User>("SomeTestId");
```

Below is the exception occurred in a Get call

> "error occurred while deserializing the UserRoles property of class
> devportal.capability.repository.Models.User: Cannot deserialize a
> 'List' from BsonType 'String'. ---> System.FormatException:
> Cannot deserialize a 'List' from BsonType 'String'."

on this line

```
var asyncCursor = await dbCollection.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

Please advise.

Comment: Check your document in MongoDB. Does the `UserRoles` field in all documents is `Array` type?

Comment: yes it is an array type

Comment: I think this is a problem with Entity because this code works.
User u = new User() { UserRoles = new List<UserRole>() { new UserRole() { RoleId = 1, RoleName = "Test" } } };
var t = u.ToJson();
var u0 = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(t);